# Proving that $\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}+1}+1}+1}+1} = \phi$

Tags: proof-writing

I have this statement:

> Prove that $\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}+1}+1}+1}+1} = \phi$

I have tried to develop algebraically, without having anything concrete. I have only obtained the longest problem, since I have tried to raise to 2 to eliminate roots.

So, how can I prove this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I presume $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$. Can you prove that $\sqrt{1+\phi}=\phi$? If so
then
$$\phi=\sqrt{\phi+1}=\sqrt{\sqrt{\phi+1}+1}=\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\phi+1}+1}+1}=
\cdots$$
*ad nausueam*.

Comment: This is the first time I have seen "ad nausueam." What does it define and when is it used? Is is like QED?

Comment: Well, that's easy to prove. But how can I be sure that it will be true if I add more roots?

Comment: Is a inductive proof?